# Mostrar información de una imagen concreta al hacer click en ella (PHP y mySql)

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

Estoy haciendo una web con PHP y mySql y hice una galeria de imagenes con el objetivo de que al pulsar en la imagen me lleve a la información especifica de ese dato en la tabla, pero no se como hacerlo y tampoco se como buscar información similar para poder hacerlo.
La galeria que he hecho:
[image]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esto sería lo que quiero que me muestre, la imagen del propio animal que he pulsado y la información correspondiente que hay en la tabla sobre ese animal.
Dejo aqui el codigo con el que he hecho la galería:

Código del html donde indico que información quiero que salga en la galería (solo el trozo que incluye el php especificando que quiero que muestre de la tabla):

```
     <div class="container">
        <?php foreach ($mostrar as $resultado){ ?>
            
            <div class="card">
            <img src="<?php echo $resultado->img ?>">
            <h5><?php echo $resultado->nombre; ?></h5>
            <button>Detalles</button> 
        </div>
           <?php 
           
        }
           ?> 
                  
                  
                  
        </div>
```

Código donde hago la consulta a la BD:

```
class Animales {
    public function visualizar() {
 
        require 'config.php';
        //realiza una consulta a la tabla animal
$registros = $base->query("SELECT a.id,a.nombre,a.edad,a.sexo,a.tamanyo,a.esterilizado,a.tipo_animal 
    as 'tipo',p.nombre as 'protectora',r.tipo as 'raza',i.url as 'img'
FROM animal a 
INNER JOIN imagenes i 
    on i.id=(select i2.id from imagenes i2 where i2.id_animal=a.id limit 1)
    INNER JOIN raza r on (a.raza=r.id)
    INNER JOIN protectora p on (p.id=a.id_protectora);")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); //almacenamos un array de obj

return $registros;
    
    }
}
```

Comment: WOW si te esta quedando muy bien y en cuanto hacer click en una imagen puedes usar HTML y CSS ya que PHP lo admite y yo lo he estado usando.

Comment: @JavierG.Raya muchas gracias! pero me refiero a que me muestre los datos de una fila en concreto de la tabla de la bd al pulsar en la imagen. Por ejemplo, si pulso la imagen de Emperador, que me muestre (en otra pagina, pero esto ya es cuestión de html) los datos de la fila en la que está emperador concretamente, es que es díficil de explicar, pero es como cuando haces una tienda y al pulsar en el articulo te muestra los detalles.

Comment: es decir si son 5 peros que te muestren los detalles de esos 5 perros no?

Comment: @JavierG.Raya si, pero individualmente

Comment: Si lo quieres hacer solo con PHP lo podrías hacer mediante **GET**, por ejemplo, ```<a href="detalles.php?id=<?php echo $resultado->id ?>">Detalles</a>``` y luego en la página **detalles.php** puedes obtener el *id* así: ```$id = $_GET['id'] ?? '';``` con eso ya podrías obtener un solo resultado por su ID.

Comment: Puedes hacer uso de un modal en lugar que te habrá otra pagina, y desde el mismo botón le envías los datos al modal , ya dentro del modal ajustas la estructura de como es que quieras mostrar la información

Comment: @DBE me serviría la consulta que hago en la funcion de la clase o necesitaría crear otra??

Comment: Sí, lo único que le debes añadir es un ```WHERE a.id = $id``` esto iría al final despues de **INNER JOIN**, y así obtienes los resultados por dicho ID, aunque si usas PDO sería mejor ```WHERE a.id = :id``` y después haces un **bindValue()**, aquí puedes ver cómo funciona bindValue: https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.bindvalue.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes pasar parámetros a tu **URL** y estos en PHP se obtienen mediante `$_GET['nombre_parametro']`. Ahora sabiendo esto puedes hacer algo como:

```
<a href="detalles.php?id=<?php echo $resultado->id; ?>">Detalles</a>
```

o más amigable:

```
<a href="detalles.php?nombre=<?php echo $resultado->nombre; ?>&id=<?php echo $resultado->id; ?>">Detalles</a>
```

Esta parte la tienes que añadir donde creas tu galería dentro del `foreach {}`, simplemente cambialo por el **button**

Ahora veamos la nueva parte, para obtener el resultado en detalles, tu función la deberías adaptar algo como:

```
// Tu nueva función
public function visualizarById(int $id)
{     
    require 'config.php';

    //realiza una consulta a la tabla animal
    $registros = $base->prepare("SELECT a.id,a.nombre,a.edad,a.sexo,a.tamanyo,a.esterilizado,a.tipo_animal 
    as 'tipo',p.nombre as 'protectora',r.tipo as 'raza',i.url as 'img'
        FROM animal AS a 
  INNER JOIN imagenes AS i on i.id=(select i2.id from imagenes i2 where i2.id_animal=a.id limit 1)
  INNER JOIN raza AS r on (a.raza=r.id)
  INNER JOIN protectora AS p on (p.id=a.id_protectora) 
       WHERE a.id = :id");
    // Pasamos el parametro :id
    $registros->bindValue(:id, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    // Ejecutas sentencias
    $registros->execute();
    $resultado = $registro->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); 

    return $resultado;    
}
```

Página **detalles.php** quedaría así:

```
<?php 
// El id y nombre existe por GET
if (isset($_GET['nombre']) && isset($_GET['id'])) :
    // Obtienes el nombre
    $nombre_perro = $_GET['nombre'] ?? '';
    // Obtienes el ID  
    $id = $_GET['id'] ?? '';

    // Obtienes datos desde la nueva función
    // 
    // añades tu clase
    require 'tu_clase_animales';
    // Instancias objeto
    $obj = new Animales();
    // Obtenemos datos por ID
    $datos = $obj->visualizarById($id);
else:
    // si no existe parametros puedes redirecionar a la galeria
    header("location: galeria.php");
endif;
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Para que cogo efectos tus estilos es importante usar la ruta absoluta o algo como ./estilos.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dominio.com/estilos.css">
    <title><?php echo $nombre_perro; ?></title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        // Muestras tu datos
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($datos);
        echo '<pre>';
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Te aconsejo una vez que lo tengas funcionando que investigues sobre cómo crear **URL amigables** con *.htaccess*, y asi podrías logras algo como:

```
dominio.com/detalles/Luna/5
```

y no algo como:

```
dominio.com/detalles.php?nombre=Luna&id=5
```

Te dejo el Manual de [bindValue](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.bindvalue.php)

Answer (score 1):

```html
<button type="button"  class="btn btn-success transfer"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalDetalles<?=$Id_Animal?>"   data-id_animal="<?=$Id_Animal?>" data-raza="<?=$razaAnimal?>" data-edad="<?=$Edad?>" data-tamano="<?=$Tamanyo?>"data-keyboard="false" data_backdrop="static" title="DETALLES"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tag"></span>
</button>
```

el botón almacena los valores de cada imagen o animal, mediante una función en js se transfieren los datos al modal,  la linea del modal puede o no llevar el id del animal,  ya que si le pones el Id sera un modal por cada botón de detalles, si no lo utilizas el id animal tendrás un solo modal genérico y dependiendo del botón que hagas clic serán los datos que se transferirán al modal

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

            $('#modalDetalles<?=$Id_Animal?>').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {

                  var button = $(event.relatedTarget); // Botón que activó el modal
                  var raza = button.data('raza'); // Extraer la información de atributos de datos
                  var edad = button.data('edad'); // Extraer la información de atributos de datos
                  var tamano = button.data('tamanyo'); // Extraer la información de atributos de datos
                  //alert(Numero_Empleado + Nombre_Empleado);

                  var modal = $(this);
                  modal.find('.modal-title').text('DETALLES:');
                  modal.find('.modal-body #raza').text(raza);
                  modal.find('.modal-body #tamano').text(tamano);
                  modal.find('.modal-body #edad').val(edad);
                  $('.alert').hide();//Oculto alert
            });  

      });
```

para la carga del modal puedes revisar esta pagina: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

es solo una idea.

Comment: muchas gracias por la idea, pero hacerlo de forma modal no se adapta a lo que quiero hacer, de todas formas gracias de nuevo!